# Spring injects null instead of a class instance

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-3, spring-java-config

Here's a piece of Spring config file:

```
@Bean
public GenericDao<Foo> fooDao() {
    return new GenericDao<>(Foo.class);
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("fooDao")
public GenericService<Foo> fooService() {
    return new ApplicationGenericService<>(fooDao(), applicationMessageProducer());
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("fooService")
public GenericService<Foo> decoratedFooService() {
    return new ServiceDecorator<>(fooService(), decoratorService());
}
```

For some reason, Spring passes `null` to `ApplicationGenericService` constructor.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: yes, null is injected to `fooService`

Comment: Why would this be Spring's fault? You're instantiating the components manually (via the `new` keyword), not wiring them from the Spring Context. If `fooDao()` returns `null`, it means that `new GenericDao<>(Foo.class)` is `null`.

Comment: Can you post the full class? Is your class annotated with @Configuration? It is possible that the annotations are not being detected for some reason.